# I am trying to select a value from drop down list in python selenium but not able to do it. Please guide

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Since select class in my code is inside div class, I cannot directly select elements using visible text or value. So I am adding all the drop-down options (elements) in a list and then trying to select a value from the list. My code is not showing any error but it is also not selecting a value from the list. It's only printing all the options in the list. Here is my code:

```
select_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='form-row row-inline addeditaddressStates required']/div[1]/select")

actions = ActionChains(driver)

actions.move_to_element(select_box).click().perform()

options = [x for x in select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

for element in options:
  print(element.get_attribute("value"))

if (element.text == ("Virginia")):
  element.click()
```

Please rectify the error if there is any.

Comment: Can you paste more information  like your relevant  DOM and does click event getting  performed correctly? After click did u check DOm again is it changed or property is still the same?

Comment: what happens if you click only one, f.e. : options[0].click()?